# nodejs Cycle and callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Recently i wrote a blog with nodejs,when it comes to add some tags to posts,problems occured.In my view, the relation between posts and tags is many-to-many,each post has several tags,in turn,each tag also match to some posts.So i create a tag collection and a post collection in mongodb.

```
exports.Post=mongolass.model("Post",{
        author:{type:Mongolass.Types.ObjectId,ref:"User"},
        title:{type:"string"},
        content:{type:"string"},
        pv:{type:"number"},
       tagIds:[{tagId::Mongolass.Types.ObjectId}]
    });
    exports.Tag=mongolass.model("Tag",{
      tagName:{type:"string"}
    });
    exports.Tag.index({tagName:1},{unique:true}).exec();
```

and store the tag as an array in posts.As we know,when i create a post, i will get the post's tagName from html by method POST,so i have to use

```
 getTagByName:function getTagByName(tagName){
            return Tag.find({tagName:tagName}).exec();
        }
```

to get the object tag,and use

```
TagModel.getTagByName(tagName).then(function(tag){
        var postToTag={
        postId:postId,
        tagId:tag[0]._id
      };
```

to get the tagId,Unfortunately, as a post has many tags,so i have to use a for cycle to get all tagId of a post, i also want to collect these tagIds to an Array, thus i can push it to my Post model, but the cycle and callback make it difficult.
any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You mean [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/). Which is essentially shorthand for `$or` but against the same property. Takes a "list" of values to match against any of those provided. It's actually mentioned on the very first thing you should be reading before you write a single query for MongoDB. [MongoDB Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

Comment: The popurse is to push an array of tagId to Post model, any middleware helpful is okey. appreciate your answer.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Which one are you doing? Reading tags off of post? Or reading tags from somewhere else to be added to a post? Reading them from where? If the latter is the case that is. Not really helping that you seem to have picked an obscure driver implementation of which no-one here has ever asked a question regarding before.

Comment: i'm sorry to not express my meaning clearly,but i've said i get the tagNames  from the html form by the method  POST.the tagNames i get is not single string, and the only solution i've thought is to use the method "getTagByName" to get the object,thus i can get the tagId,but as you can see,the shortcome of the solution is that i can only get single id,so i create a for-cycle to get all id of a post,since the feature of callback, i cannot push these id to fill the Post Model.i've fill the rest of Post Model except this.